# kendo ui grid header not displaying

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, knockout-kendo

I have a kendo grid that is bind to the observablearray in knockout

```
  <div data-bind="kendoGrid: { data: UserInPlan 
                        rowTemplate: 'rowTmpl', 
                        scrollable: true, 
                        sortable: true, 
                        pageable: { pageSize: 10 }, useKOTemplates: true}"> </div>

 <script id="rowTmpl" type="text/html">               
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: UserFullName"></td>
            <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.RemoveUserToPlan">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
 </script>
```

Here is my sample user plan data
       { "PlanId": planId, "UserFullName": userName, "UserId": userId }

The header is not displaying.. Here is sample image

[image]

Comment: Which Kendo version are you using? It seems your code is working with the latest kendo version: http://trykendoui.telerik.com/obEV

Comment: I am using the latest version of kendo-ui  v2013.3.1324

Comment: I am facing same problem. Any one know solution for this?